# how to call screen which extends MainScreen from screen which also extends MainScreen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I push MyScreen which extends MainScreen from my UiApplication class. I've now created a splash screen which also extends MainScreen. I want to navigate from the splash screen to MyScreen. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In the UiApp, call the splashScreen by the following:

```
SplashScreen splashScreen = new SplachScreen();
pushScreen(splahScreen);
```

Then in the splashScreen, when you want to push the other screen call:

```
YourScreen yourScreen = new YourScreen();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(yourScreen);
```

Comment: Farid Farhat ,i did it but after running application my application shows 1st Splash Screen then one white screen(which i did not made in my application) and then after clicking on back button it shows my applications main screen.what to do now?

Comment: Its not a normal thing to happen. Well check if you are pushing a new MainScreen() to the screen after pushing your screen. If so don't do that. No white screens can be pushed without you pushing them

Comment: i am not pushing it .no such code i have written.thats why not understanding what is happening.When i extend splashscreen to my main screen.it shows good working but i don't want to do that .

Comment: "When i extend splashscreen to my main screen" What do you mean by this?

Comment: Well you have to have MyMainScreen extends MainScreen not SplashScreen

Comment: Farid Farhat i got invalidate() which is written in my splash Screen class.i comment that invalidate() ,now my application does not show that white screen but problem arises that Splash screen not closing automatically even i set timer(i have to close it by pressing back button or Menu->close).

Comment: just use splashScreen.close() function to close it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

in StartApp class push the splash screen and in the splash screen constructor pass the MyScreen object like this

```
MyScreen myScreen=new MyScreen();
SplashScreen splash=new SplashScreen(mainScreen);
pushScreen(splash);
```

then inside SplashScreen do pushScreen(mainScreen);

Comment: rihan it is showing me blank screen after splash screen.Also you told to write inside SplashScreen pushScreen(mainScreen) but it shows me error that pushScreen is not defined for Splash Screen( splash Screen extends MainScreen)

Comment: is above code like this --- MyScreen myScreen=new MyScreen();
SplashScreen splash=new SplashScreen(myScreen);
pushScreen(splash);

Comment: you can either create a method pushscreen() which is like this 'private void pushScreen(MainScreen screen){UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(screen)}' or replace pushScreen(mainscreen) with 'UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(mainScreen)'

Comment: rihan i got invalidate() which is written in my splash Screen class.i comment that invalidate() ,now my application does not show that white screen but problem arises that Splash screen not closing automatically even i set timer(i have to close it by pressing back button or Menu->close).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the splash screen code from [Bayes blog](http://blog.bayestech.com/?p=49) . use it in start app like

```
new splashScreen(this,new myscreen() );
```

the myscreen is a class  extend the MainScreen.

Comment: Ajmal i got invalidate() which is written in my splash Screen class.i comment that invalidate() ,now my application does not show that white screen but problem arises that Splash screen not closing automatically even i set timer(i have to close it by pressing back button or Menu->close)

Comment: I think it is not the problem of splashscreen class.it may depend on the content of myscreen class.